# Pass argument to thread

Tags: c, linux, arguments, pthreads

I'm doing my assignment about thread. I need to do 3 thread, first compute temperature value, second compute pressure value and third thread, I need to pass those value and display it. But when I'm compile, I got segmentation fault (core dumped). I need to pass the argument but doesn't know where I did wrong. Can someone help me?

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct param_t_p{

int temperature;
int LOWER_TEMP_BOUND,UPPER_TEMP_BOUND;
float pressure;
float LOWER_PRESURE_BOUND,UPPER_PRESURE_BOUND;
};



void timespec_add_us (struct timespec *t, long us)
{
    t->tv_nsec += us*1000;
        while (t->tv_nsec > 1000000000) 
        {
            t->tv_nsec = t->tv_nsec - 1000000000;// + ms*1000000;
            t->tv_sec += 1;
        }
}


void *temp (void* args)
{
    struct param_t_p *ps = (struct param_t_p *)args;
    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    while (1) 
    {
        timespec_add_us(&time, 4000000);
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME,&time, NULL);
        ps->temperature = ps->LOWER_TEMP_BOUND + (int)(ps->UPPER_TEMP_BOUND*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
        printf("First thread for temperature is done\n\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}


void *press (void* args)
{
    struct param_t_p *ps = (struct param_t_p *)args;
    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    while (1) 
    {
        timespec_add_us(&time, 4000000);
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME,&time, NULL);
        ps->pressure = ps->LOWER_PRESURE_BOUND +( int)(ps->UPPER_PRESURE_BOUND*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
        
        printf("Second thread for temperature is done\n\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *display (void* args)
{
    struct param_t_p *ps = (struct param_t_p *)args;
    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    while (1) 
    {
        timespec_add_us(&time, 4000000);
        clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME,&time, NULL);
        
        printf("Value for Temperature and Pressure\n");
        printf(" Temperature : %d°C\n", ps->temperature);
        printf(" Pressure : %.2fPa\n", ps->pressure);
        printf("Third thread is done\n\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t th1,th2,th3;
    pthread_att_t attr;
    struct sched_param param1, param2, param3;
    
    struct param_t_p data;
    data.LOWER_TEMP_BOUND=20;
    data.UPPER_TEMP_BOUND=40;
    data.LOWER_PRESURE_BOUND=31.5;
    data.UPPER_PRESURE_BOUND=32.5;
    data.temperature;
    data.pressure;
    
    
    printf("Process ID: %d\n\n", getpid());
    
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
    param1.sched_priority = 1;
    param2.sched_priority = 2;
    param3.sched_priority = 3;
    
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param1);
    pthread_create(&th1, &attr, temp, &data);
    
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param2);
    pthread_create(&th2, &attr, press, &data);
    
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param3);
    pthread_create(&th3, &attr, display, &data);
    
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    
    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);
    pthread_join(th3, NULL);
    

}
```

I need to solve it as soon as possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: Start by using a *debugger* to catch the crash and see when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: With that said, you have *data races* as multiple threads access the same data simultaneously. You need to synchronize the access to the common data.

Comment: `data.temperature; data.pressure;` what is the purpose of those lines? Do you mean `data.temperature = 0; data.pressure = 0;`?

Comment: Typo at line 82: `pthread_att_t attr;` should be `pthread_attr_t attr;`

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo, but with the correct one also got error, segmentation fault (core dumped). The data.temperature  and data.pressure suppose not to be there, I just trying to figure out the problem. The process end after showing the process ID the its show segmentation fault core dumped.